# confronting with Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected with rails 4 when iam trying to reset the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

```
 this is my home_controller.rb
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end
    end





    my routes.rb file
    devise_for :users ,:controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions"}

            devise_scope :user do
            root :to =>"users/sessions#new"
            end




my development.rb file
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.cache_classes = false

      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 587,
      user_name:"ajeet.soni10@gmail.com",
      password: "6473eyre",
      authentication: "plain",
      enable_starttls_auto: true,

    }`
```

`
so iam using url:-http://localhost:3000//signin it shows me the log in page user can singup usually but when user wants to reset his password 
by clicking on forgot password the whole page is halted with a redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem in routes.rb file i rectified that file and it worked

Login::Application.routes.draw do

```
  resources :pets


#devise_for :users
```

devise_for :users ,:controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions"} 
        devise_scope :user do
        root :to =>"users/sessions#new"
        end